# WHM/cPanel: Create New Account ERROR

Tags: cpanel, centos6, whm

When creating a new account in WHM I get this error instantly when I click the Create button: 'A fatal error or timeout occurred while processing this directive'. It says 'show' for more info but its not clickable. Certain the entered information is correct. Any suggestions?

[image: Error Screenshot].

CENTOS 6.9 v66.0.29, Load Averages: 0.05 0.06 0.02

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research and time wasting this proved to be a server side issue. The host rebooted the server and reset VPS quotas and all works good now. I would recommend contacting your host first if you have the same problem.